# $response JSON return only 1 row, PHP, ANDROID

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

When I use `json_encode($response)`, it returns only the first row of the query, how to make it return all the rows?

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

main.php

```
// check for user
$user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
if ($user != false ) {
    // user found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
    $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
    $response["user"]["dega"] = $user["dega"];
    $response["user"]["salla"] = $user["salla"];
    $response["user"]["ora"] = $user["ora"];
    $response["user"]["lenda"] = $user["lenda"];
    $response["user"]["dita"] = $user["dita"];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

method.php

```
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT U.name, U.email, U.password, F.dega, 
        O.salla, O.ora, O.lenda, O.dita FROM users U 
         INNER JOIN fakulteti F on U.id = F.studenti 
           INNER JOIN orari O on F.id = O.fakulteti WHERE email = '$email'")  or die(mysql_error());

    $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $encrypted_password = $result['password']
        if ($encrypted_password == $password) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Android class and this is how I recieve a response on my android:

```
JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
String name = user.getString("name");
String email = user.getString("email");
String dega = user.getString("dega");
String salla = user.getString("salla");
String ora = user.getString("ora");
String lenda = user.getString("lenda");
String dita = user.getString("dita");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly creating an array to handle only one row in your main.php

You would need to loop through the results with a while() (for instance) to build your array with multiple rows.

But the query looks like it only brings one record anyway... or there are more then 1 student with the same e-mail?

Comment: the query is right for my purpose because I tested it and it gives me 3 rows, but I don't know how to do that for making a while()

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() brings ONE row and moves the pointer to the next...
so somthing like
`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}`